# How to call jQuery colorbox with javascript onClick event instead of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I want to call colorbox using javascript rather than a href link?

anyone know how I can do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The previous examples didn't work for me, but using the same idea, this does work:

```
<script>
function lightbox(){    
  $.colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, href:"/pagetoopen.html"});
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="open the box" onClick="lightbox()"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is off the top of my head. But I believe you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_cbox()
{
   jQuery.colorbox({html:'<p>Hi There I was instantiated onclick!</p>'});
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="call_cbox(); return false;">Give me a colorbox... NOW! And don't forget the color.</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

A mix of the two answers above worked for me:

```
<script>
function call_cbox()
{
jQuery().colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", iframe:true, href:"/newsletter.html"});
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that this isn't working for me anymore. I don't know if it was from a Colorbox update or a jquery update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").click(function () { 

    $.colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", iframe:true, href:"http://www.google.com"});

});
```